# Sorting Posts Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

New to rails as a whole, but looking around I don't see any gems or in-depth tutorials about sorting posts in rails by 'likes' or 'comments' or by a certain field. I was wondering if you guys know any youtube clips or where you learnt this? Or just any gems that I could use the scaffold of?

Thanks again!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are _off-topic_ for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: This question needs some info about your specific schema, and precisely what you want to do.  it's too vague as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, you have a model Post and a database table posts and want to get the posts ordered by 'likes'?

Use the [ActiveRecord Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

In your case you can use something like Post.order(:likes) (if you have a column 'likes' in your posts table)

Comment: Thanks for discussing this - I wanted a vague answer to just point me in the direction and this was perfect!